# MS Access VBA not recognizing forms in Application.Forms until they are opened

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, userform

If I run the following code:

```
  For i = 0 To Application.Forms.Count - 1
        Debug.Print Application.Forms(i).Name
  Next i
```

I am getting very strange results. The above code only recognizes forms I have *opened* or directly accessed (such as using `?mFormName.name` in the intermediate window).

Access does not seem to see the other form objects or include them as part of `Application.Forms`. This also includes referencing them by name, such as `Application.Forms("mFormName")` - this does not work either.

I have some methods which run by iterating through a variety of forms and I would like to avoid having to open them all in order for the Access VBE to recognize them in this fashion.

- How can I iterate through my Access forms without manually opening/referencing them first? `Application.Forms` seems really buggy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the `Application.Forms` collection includes only opened forms. To iterate through all forms you can use the `Application.CurrentProject.AllForms` collection.

Comment: Gosh some stuff in Access drives me nuts. Thanks. I'll accept this once enough time passes..